# Finding a list of things nested a few layers deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a training week that has_many workouts. Each Workout has_many exercises. I'm trying to write a method on the training week class that tells me all the exercises that are in a training week.

I'm using Rails. The ultimate would be to be able to do something as simple as TrainingWeek.exercises the same way I can do Workout.exercises.

Any ideas? My ultimate goal is to get a a json output something like this:

```
"exercise": [
    {                    
        "name": "Bench Dips 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hanging Leg Raises 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bench Press 0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bicep Curls 0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lat Pulldowns 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bench Dips 0"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this association to your `TrainingWeek` model:

```
has_many :exercises, :through => :workouts, :uniq => true
```

Then you can just do:

```
@some_training_week.exercises
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know you could do that!! Thanks! What does :uniq do?

Comment: You can have the same exercise associated through different workouts. If you don't specify `:uniq => true` it would appear in the resulting array multiple times. I just assumed you don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@training_week = TrainingWeek.find(...)

@schedule_hash = { "exercise" => @training_week.workouts.inject(Array.new) { |workout, array| array << { "name" => workout.name }; array } }
```

At this point, `@schedule_hash` should be close to what you want.  I haven't tested this, but that should be pretty close.